# Check whether a particular vertex exists or not in gremlin traversal

Tags: titan, gremlin, tinkerpop

I am trying to check first that whether a particular Vertex Exists in a graph or not if, it doesn't exists then i am creating a new vertex, the checker is based on properties , Here is the following code :

```
public Vertex addVertex(Enum label, Map properties){

    Vertex x = null;int fl=0,f=0;

    if(properties.size()==0)
    return null;

    GraphTraversalSource g = graph.traversal();
    Set<Enum> keys = properties.keySet();
    for(Enum key: keys){
        f++;
        properties.get(key);
        System.out.println("enter");
        if(g.V().hasLabel(label.toString()).has(key.toString(),properties.get(key)).next()!=null  ){
        fl++;
        System.out.println("exit");
        x=  g.V().hasLabel(label.toString()).has(key.toString(),properties.get(key)).next();
        System.out.println("exit2");
        }
    }
    if(fl==f){
        return x;
    }
    x=graph.addVertex(T.label,label.toString(),properties);
    return x;
}
```

But i am getting the following error .

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.util.FastNoSuchElementException
```

How can this be solved, any leads will be really appreciated

Comment: This question was cross-posted and answered on the Titan mailing list
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/aureliusgraphs/voshQUP2Fbw/QYI6Jx5-AwAJ

Answer (score 1):

Traversal implements Iterator, so you should start by appending `.hasNext()` to your Traversal. The exception is being thrown when you attempt to `next()` the Iterator when no values are left.